# Evaluating Regression Neural Network model's accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss

I am new to machine learning and created a neural network for regression output. I have ~95000 training examples and ~24000 test examples. I want to know how can I evaluate my model and get train and test errors? How to know the accuracy of this regression model? My Y variable values ranges between 100-200 and X have 9 input features in the dataset.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Importing the dataset
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data2csv.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:,1:10].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, :1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Initialising the ANN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 9))

# Adding the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding the third hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer

model.add(Dense(units = 1))

#model.add(Dense(1))
# Compiling the ANN
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['mae','mse','mape','cosine'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data=(X_val, y_val) ,batch_size = 1000, epochs = 100)
test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)

loss = history.history['loss']
acc = history.history['mean_absolute_error']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
val_acc = history.history['val_mean_absolute_error']
mape_loss=history.history['mean_absolute_percentage_error']
cosine_los=history.history['cosine_proximity']
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['cosine_proximity'])
pyplot.show()
epochs = range(1, len(loss)+1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'ro', label='Training loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

plt.plot(y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Real data')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted data')
plt.title('Prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[[image: Results]]

My test loss after model.evaluate. Note that here there are 5 loss functions as shown in the code.

1) 84.69654303799824
2) 7.030169963975834
3) 84.69654303799824
4) 5.241855282313331
5) -0.9999999996023872

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate your model you can use [`evaluate`](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate) method:

```
test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

It returns the loss on the given test data computed using the same loss function you used during training (i.e. `mean_squared_error`).
Further, If you want to get training loss at the end of each epoch you can use `History` object [which is returned](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) by `fit` method:

```
history = model.fit(...)
loss = history.history['loss']
```

The `loss` is a list containing the loss values of training at the end of each epoch. If you have used validation data when training the model (i.e. `model.fit(..., validation_data=(X_val, y_val)`) or have used any other metric like `mean_absolute_error` (i.e. `model.compile(..., metrics=['mae'])`), you can also access their values:

```
acc = history.history['mae']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
val_acc = history.history['val_mae']
```

---

**Bonus:** To plot the training loss curve:

```
epochs = range(1, len(loss)+1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'ro', label='Training loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. How to understand that my model is good after I see these results?

Comment: @user123098 Well, it entirely depends on the problem you are working on and what you define a "good" loss. Of course, in case of using `mean_squared_error` as loss, it is better to be close to zero. However, for example if you are trying to predict temperature of tomorrow, then a mean squared loss of one means that on average your predictions are one degree off. You may consider this precision "excellent", "good", "not bad" or "just terrible". I hope it's clear what I am trying to say.

Comment: Yeah, my last epoch gives a loss mse of around 45.7. My dataset is huge and it has one dependent variable Y which depends on 9 input features of X. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: @user123098 I can't tell you anything. MSE of 45.7 means an average error of sqrt(45.7) ~= 6.8. Is 6.8 error considered good? Well, the only thing I can say is that if Y values are big then (e.g. in range [1000, 10000]) then average error of is very good. Otherwise if they are very small (e.g. [1-10] or [0-1]) then it's not good and you need to modify the architecture or parameters of your model or gather more training data. You should define a validation set and compare the training error and validation error. If training error is very small and validation error is big then you are >>>>

Comment: overfitting. To prevent overfitting you can add regularization, gather more training data, decrease the network size, etc. BTW, I could not understand the error you get when evaluating. Could you update the code in your question to include the evaluation part? And please mention there the error you get,

Comment: Edited. Kindly check

Comment: @user123098 Sorry that I have forgotten to pass `y_test` to `evaluate` method in my answer. Now it is fixed. Your model is overfitting since 1) the training loss have been decreasing during the training, and 2) at epoch 100 the training loss is ~58 and the validation loss is ~380. So that's a clear sign of overfitting. You can prevent it with the methods I mentioned in my previous comment (search for more methods in Google). e.g. try increasing the dropout rate from 0.2 to 0.5 and see if it helps (BTW, change the activation function of second layer to `relu`). Or add weight regularization.

Answer (score 0):

To show validation loss while training:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 1000, epochs = 100, validation_data = (y_train,y_test))
```

I don't think you can easily get accuracy by plotting, since your input is 9 dimensional, you could plot the predicted y for each feature, just turn off the lines that join the dots i.e. plt.plot(x,y,'k.') note 'k' so no line, but I'm not sure if that will be useful.